# Is it possible to create a custom chart type in salesforce (one that can be used in reports)?

Tags: reporting, custom, custom-reports, charts

Salesforce reports lets you pick from a number of chart types (bar, line, pie etc), is it possible to extend these types for my org?

I want to create my own chart type and make it available in the salesforce report builder tool? What if I want a a chart that is not one of the 8 charts defined? What if I want a bubble chart, a org chart, combo chart etc?

Comment: What do you mean "extend" these types? You're limited to what you see in terms of options and what you can edit within each type.

Comment: I mean create my own chart type? What if I want a a chart that is not one of the 8 charts defined? What if I want a bubble chart, a org chart, combo chart etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're limited to the charts defined in [Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=chart_types.htm&type=5) for use in reports.

I'd suggest putting an idea in for any chart types you'd like to see and look around for existing ideas. I see some for [histograms](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HHUhAAO), [Venn Diagrams](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015BFRQA2), [box plot](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNayQAE), and I'm sure there might be others.

Otherwise, you could explore custom options that use [Chart.js and lighting components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/03/building-lightning-components-chart-js.html), but you'd have to weigh the pros and cons of doing something like that and understand you wouldn't really be able to put that within a report in Salesforce.